# JPA Foreign key INSERT

Tags: java, jpa, foreign-keys, persist

Good morning in my timezone:

I have the following class structure:

class C1

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator ="seqG")
 @Column(name = "ID_IDENTIFIER_C")
 private Long id;

 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "V1",cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
 private C2 var1;
```

class C2

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID_IDENTIFIER_C")
private Long id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_IDENTIFIER_C", insertable = false, updatable =     false)
private C1 var;
```

When I try to persist a new entity(object) of the class `C1`, it throws the following exception

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("AGILE"."T_C2_TABLE"."ID_IDENTIFIER_C")
```

When I insert the class `C1`, I do not have the `id` fullfilled, because it is generated by the sequence generator, so how do I solve this problem ? Should I first insert just the object `C1`, then retrieve the `id` and then `INSERT` the object `C2`? Is there a way to do it all at once ?

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: Why you are again using @OneToOne on C1 in class C2 ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to archive: Why has `C2.id` and `C2.var` the same column? If you look at your error message you will see, that it is complaining about the ID column of C2, not about C1.